# Не работает символ в switch

Tags: c, switch

У меня следующая проблема. Переписал калькулятор с обратной польской записью (K&R) таким образом, чтобы операторы и операнды задавались как аргументы командной строки (упр 5.10). Код получился таким:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXOP 100
#define  NUMBER 1

int getop(char *s, char *t);
void push(double f);
double pop(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int type;
    double op2;
    char s[MAXOP];
    char *s1 = s;
    int i = 1;

    while (--argc > 0)
    {
        type = getop(s1, argv[i++]);
        switch (type)
        {
            case NUMBER:
            {
                push (atof(s1));
                break;
            }
            case '+':
            {
                push (pop() + pop());
                break;
            }
            case '*':
            {
                push (pop() * pop());
                break;
            }
            case '-':
            {
                op2 = pop();
                push (pop() - op2);
                break;
            }
            case '/':
            {
                op2 = pop();
                if (op2 != 0.0)
                    push (pop() / op2);
                else
                    printf("ERROR: zero divide\n");
                break;
            }
            case '%':
            {
                op2 = pop();
                if (op2 != 0.0)
                    push ((int)pop() % (int)op2);
                else
                    printf("ERROR: zero divide\n");
                break;
            }      
            default:
            {
                printf("ERROR: unknown operation %s\n", s1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf ("%g", pop());
    return 0;
}
```

Программа работает корректно, выдает результат, кроме одного НО. Когда в командной строке задается операнд `*`, например, `polskaukaz.exe 3.8 2 *` получается следующий результат

```
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
ERROR: unknown operation 2
2
```

При этом, если я задам в switch другой символ вместо умножения, например `m`, то программа срабатывает корректно.

```
polskaukaz.exe 3.8 2 m
7.6
```

В чем проблема? Почему программа ругается именно на этот символ? (Предыдущий калькулятор, где операнды и операторы задаются после запуска программы обрабатывают умножение корректно).

Реализация getop()

```
int getop(char *s, char *t)
{
    int i, c;

    while ((c = *t) != '\0')
    {    
        if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
            return c;
        else if (c == '.')
        {
            *s++ = c;
            t++; 
        }    
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            *s++ = c;
            t++; 
        }
    }
    *s = '\0';
    return NUMBER;
}
```

**P.S.**
По совету Александра воспользовался отладчиком. Получилось, что при встрече с `'*'` getop() возвращает 97 вместо 42. Тем не менее, это ни на шаг не приблизило меня к ответу на вопрос, почему программа так поступает (остальные знаки возвращают корректные значения).

Для наглядности чуть изменил первый `while`, чтобы видеть сразу что записывается в `type`

```
while (--argc > 0)
    {
        type = getop(s1, argv[i++]);
        printf ("%d %d\n",n++, type);
        switch (type)
```

n - просто счетчик строк
В случае с "нормальными" знаками результат следующий

```
polskaukaz.exe 3 4 +
1 1
2 1
3 43
7
```

Дважды напечатан NUMBER, затем код `+` - 43 и результат.

В случае `*`

```
polskaukaz.exe 3 4 *
1 1
2 1
3 97
ERROR: unknown operation 4
4 97
ERROR: unknown operation 4
5 97
ERROR: unknown operation 4
6 97
ERROR: unknown operation 4
7 97
ERROR: unknown operation 4
8 97
ERROR: unknown operation 4
9 97
ERROR: unknown operation 4
10 97
ERROR: unknown operation 4
11 97
ERROR: unknown operation 4
12 98
ERROR: unknown operation 4
13 98
ERROR: unknown operation 4
14 100
ERROR: unknown operation 4
15 100
ERROR: unknown operation 4
16 101
ERROR: unknown operation 4
17 101
ERROR: unknown operation 4
18 101
ERROR: unknown operation 4
19 101
ERROR: unknown operation 4
20 101
ERROR: unknown operation 4
21 101
ERROR: unknown operation 4
22 102
ERROR: unknown operation 4
23 102
ERROR: unknown operation 4
24 103
ERROR: unknown operation 4
25 103
ERROR: unknown operation 4
26 103
ERROR: unknown operation 4
27 103
ERROR: unknown operation 4
28 103
ERROR: unknown operation 4
29 103
ERROR: unknown operation 4
30 104
ERROR: unknown operation 4
31 104
ERROR: unknown operation 4
32 104
ERROR: unknown operation 4
33 104
ERROR: unknown operation 4
34 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
35 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
36 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
37 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
38 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
39 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
40 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
41 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
42 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
43 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
44 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
45 105
ERROR: unknown operation 4
46 107
ERROR: unknown operation 4
47 107
ERROR: unknown operation 4
48 107
ERROR: unknown operation 4
49 107
ERROR: unknown operation 4
50 107
ERROR: unknown operation 4
51 108
ERROR: unknown operation 4
52 108
ERROR: unknown operation 4
53 109
ERROR: unknown operation 4
54 109
ERROR: unknown operation 4
55 109
ERROR: unknown operation 4
56 109
ERROR: unknown operation 4
57 77
ERROR: unknown operation 4
58 112
ERROR: unknown operation 4
59 112
ERROR: unknown operation 4
60 112
ERROR: unknown operation 4
61 112
ERROR: unknown operation 4
62 112
ERROR: unknown operation 4
63 112
ERROR: unknown operation 4
64 112
ERROR: unknown operation 4
65 112
ERROR: unknown operation 4
66 112
ERROR: unknown operation 4
67 112
ERROR: unknown operation 4
68 113
ERROR: unknown operation 4
69 113
ERROR: unknown operation 4
70 114
ERROR: unknown operation 4
71 114
ERROR: unknown operation 4
72 114
ERROR: unknown operation 4
73 114
ERROR: unknown operation 4
74 114
ERROR: unknown operation 4
75 114
ERROR: unknown operation 4
76 114
ERROR: unknown operation 4
77 114
ERROR: unknown operation 4
78 114
ERROR: unknown operation 4
79 114
ERROR: unknown operation 4
80 114
ERROR: unknown operation 4
81 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
82 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
83 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
84 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
85 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
86 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
87 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
88 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
89 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
90 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
91 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
92 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
93 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
94 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
95 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
96 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
97 115
ERROR: unknown operation 4
98 116
ERROR: unknown operation 4
99 116
ERROR: unknown operation 4
100 117
ERROR: unknown operation 4
101 117
ERROR: unknown operation 4
102 117
ERROR: unknown operation 4
103 117
ERROR: unknown operation 4
104 121
ERROR: unknown operation 4
105 121
ERROR: unknown operation 4
4
```

Меня не интересуют "известные" методы реализации - я понимаю как работает программа, но меня интересует почему getop() в случае одного конкретного символа возвращает неверный результат, да еще и разворачивается в непонятный цикл из сотни итераций. Я действительно что-то проглядел? Или это ошибка системы?

P.P.S Если использовать запись вида

```
polskaukaz.exe 3 4 *4
1 1
2 1
3 42
12
```

То результат получается корректным. Получается что чистый `*` нельзя использовать в качестве аргумента?

Comment: Так а реализация `getop` где?

Comment: Извините, добавил

Comment: Для начала, я бы поставил точку прерывания на  "type = getop(s1, argv[i++]);"  и посмотрел, что там приходит в проблемном случае.

Comment: Локализуйте проблему. Сделайте минимальный пример, в котором вы только считываете символы из командной строки и выводите их коды. Например,  если вы ввели `3 * 4` и программа вывела значения `51 42 52`, а затем ввели `3 4 *` и программа вывела `51 52 97`, то это хороший повод полностью переписать вопрос и спросить в чём причина такого поведения.

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо @wololo за мысль. Источник проблем найден. Дело в том, что символ `*` - это символ-джокер, который при использовании в командной строке в качестве аргумента расширяется до перечисления имен всех файлов в текущей директории (именно поэтому он выводит такую монструозную конструкцию в качестве результата, чтобы это проверить достаточно использовать `printf("%s", argv[i++])`). Тем, кто столкнется с этой проблемой впоследствии, в разных источниках советуют передавать этот символ в командной строке, как `"*"` или `'*'` или `\*` или `"\*"` в зависимости от ОС. Лично у меня ни один из вариантов не сработал ни в powershell'е, ни в cmd. Символ все равно интерпретируется как джокер, с тем лишь отличием, что в последних двух вариантах он расширяется до перечисления имен директорий и файлов уровнем выше. Придется остановиться на `x` для умножения. Всем спасибо.

Comment: кажется заворачивание в кавычки работает. Не помню только в одинарные или в двойные

Comment: Ну в моем случае не сработал ни один вариант. Возможно есть ещё какие то варианты

Comment: у меня в cmd '*'  не разворачивается в список файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит так будто сама оболочка из которой вы запускаете свою программу заменяет * на что-то другое. Так например делает bash, заменяя звездочку на имена всех файлов в текущем каталоге. Попробуйте проверить это напечатав все переданные аргументы printf-ом.

Comment: Да, уже разобрался